# stripe table groups with jquery skipping specific tr's

Tags: jquery, css

I have been banging my head on this one for too long.

I have a basic table (all the TR's except the ones that include th's are classes with classme)

```
<table>
<tr class="classme"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr class="classme"><td>1a</td></tr>
<tr class="classme"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="classme"><td>2a</td></tr>
<tr><th>skip me</th></tr>
<tr class="classme"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr class="classme"><td>3a</td></tr>
<tr ...><td>4</td></tr>
<tr ...><td>4a</td></tr>
<tr ...><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>5a</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>8a</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td></tr>
<tr><td>9a</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>10a</td></tr>
<tr><th>skip me</th></tr>
<tr><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>11a</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>12a</td></tr>
</table>
```

That I would like to stripe with a tr background color.

I am using jQuery and have found a few posts on here and Google relate to the stripping but have failed to find something that skips arbitrary rows.

I have attempted...

```
$("tr:nth-child(4n)").addClass("alt").prev().addClass("alt");
```

which works great, but it counts the ones I want to skip.

and

```
$("tr:not(tr th):nth-child(4n)").addClass("alt").prev().addClass("alt");
```

with no luck.  I even tried to assign a variable to the result of

```
var trs = $(".classme"); 
$(trs + ":nth-child(4n)").addClass("alt").prev().addClass("alt");
```

but it still counted applied the style incorrectly.

How do I set a set of selected elements such that the rows I want to exclude are not in the count when the add class is put onto the element?

**Edit:**
I would like to stripe (in the table example) 1,1a,3,3a,5,5a.  So I consider 1 and 1a to be a group.  I want to stripe every other group.

**Edit:**
updated with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgNpY/1)

Comment: so the problem is to select all the trs except the ones which are headers?

Comment: @Th0rndike - I updated the question.  I would like to stripe every other group, with a group being 1 and 1a, 3 and 3a. etc.

Comment: So does the CSS classme part somehow effect the outcome? I'm not seeing how that fits in.

Comment: do all grouped tr's need to be "classme"?  can we alternate class names between groups? so 1/1a are "classme" and 2/2a are "classyou" and so on.

Comment: @j08691 no I put them in there if they helped.  If they are not needed, they can be removed.

Comment: @chrisvillanueva it's possible, but then I would be using php to do the class work.  I guess I could just stripe them with php, but seems like jQuery should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rows=   $('.classme:last').nextAll().not(':has(th)');
rows.filter(':even').addClass('evenClass)
```

Edit .skips lower th tag now

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/YXDMH/

EDIT: all rows without `TH` included

```
var rows=   $('tr').not(':has(th)');
rows.filter(':even').addClass('evenClass').end().filter(':odd').addClass('odd')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YXDMH/1/

Comment: I think that still styles the tr/th combo

Comment: not 100% sure if ignoring classme is correst, but added demo skips the lower one with th tag

Comment: I think what you want is just use `rows=$('tr').not(':has(th)');`..the `classme` was a bit confusing